# Finding depletion region without built in potential

Tags: diodes, semiconductors, physics

I am trying to solve a problem as to find the depletion region's width of a p+-n-n diode. I am given the width of the first n region and the doping of both n regions.

Here is the problem:

[image]

I believe that I have to use some boundary conditions of the electric field to find out what it must be and then integrate the result to find the built in potential, but I am not sure how exactly to go about this.

Answer (score 1):

So the "sophisticated" says you solve Poisson's equation. in the depletion region.  Really that means keeping track of charge conservation.
Equal and opposite charges on each side of the region.

Is that enough for you to solve it?

Comment: not really, since i dont have the doping concentration of the p+ side.

Comment: Ah, OK if one side is much more strongly doped then the depletion region is all on the low density side, like a metal- semi schottky diode. (At least that's my understanding.) (I didn't read your question that closely.)

Comment: uh.... then that still doesnt solve my problem at all... I need to find the width of n2 region